# App doesn't work on android app emulator even though It works on web emulators properly

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, emulation

Hello I am a Beginner for flutter. I have a question with running and simulating.

When I run `flutter run` It simulates only

> Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows
> [Version 10.0.19045.3324] Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript
> • Google Chrome 116.0.5845.96 Edge (web)        • edge    •
> web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 115.0.1901.203 [1]: Windows (windows)
> [2]: Chrome (chrome) [3]: Edge (edge)

I need to simulate android app emulator. I need your help to solve this problem.

This is the error message I got (After running `flutter run`)

> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> ```
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
> > Failed to clean up output files for task ':app:packageDebug'
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 11s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> 12.4s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code

1